# Typescript - React Native: There is way to save switch button state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

There is way to save switch button state with `asyncstorage` ?
My goal is that when the user clicks on the switcher, then its state will be preserved even when the user exits the application and returns back.

```
import { View, Text, Switch } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import styles from './ViewFieldStyles';

type Props = {
  title: string;
  value: boolean;
  setValue: () => void;
};

const ViewField = ({ title, value, setValue }: Props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.optionView}>
      <View style={styles.sameRowTextView}>
        <Text style={styles.optionText}>{title}</Text>
        <View style={styles.switchView}>
          <Switch
            trackColor={{ false: '#767577', true: 'rgba(4, 76, 163, 0.38)' }}
            thumbColor={value ? '#1d16db' : '#f4f3f4'}
            ios_backgroundColor='#3e3e3e'
            onValueChange={setValue}
            value={value}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ViewField;
```

Comment: Yes you can. You will need to run an effect that whenever the screen with the switch is focused, it will retrieved the state from the asyncstorage and set your switch accordingly. However, if you have multiple users using the application, I would suggest that you save the user settings in a database instead of asyncstorage.

Comment: or use redux persist it better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that using `AsyncStorage`.
Below is an example.

Install and import module.

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
```

Then use it like below.

```
<Switch
  trackColor={{false: theme.negative, true: theme.positive}}
  onValueChange={(result) => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem(
      AsyncStorageKey.DarkMode,
      JSON.stringify(result),
    );
    changeThemeType(result ? 'dark' : 'light');
    setIsDarkMode(result);
  }}
  value={isDarkMode}
/>
```

To get the value when component loads,

```
const [isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  const setDarkMode = async (): Promise<void> => {
    const result = JSON.parse(
      (await AsyncStorage.getItem('IS_DARK')) || 'false',
    ) as boolean;

    setIsDarkMode(result);
  };

  setDarkMode();
}, []);
```